Disable hover and click on a pie slice with amCharts 5
I'm trying to find a way to disable hover and click events on pie chart slice using amCharts 5.
So far I only found a way to disable on a legend:
legend.itemContainers.template.setup = function(item) {
    item.events.disableType("click")
};


In case you want to disable effects for all slices you can try these:
// Disable hover events only
series.slices.template.set("tooltipText", null);
series.slices.template.states.create("hover", {
  scale: 1,
});

// Disable click event only
series.slices.template.set("toggleKey", "none");

In case you want to disable interactions for specific slice your code should be something like this:


let root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");
root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)]);

let chart = root.container.children.push(
  am5percent.PieChart.new(root, {
    layout: root.horizontalLayout
  })
);

let pieSeries = chart.series.push(
  am5percent.PieSeries.new(root, {
    valueField: "value",
    categoryField: "category"
  })
);

pieSeries.data.setAll([
  { category: "Category A", value: 20 },
  { category: "Category B", value: 20 },
  { category: "Category C", value: 60 }
]);


pieSeries.events.on("datavalidated", function() {
  pieSeries.dataItems.forEach((dataItem) => {
    //  Check if the slice matches your specific condition
    if (dataItem.get("category") === "Category A") {
      let slice = dataItem.get("slice");
      slice.set("interactive", false);
      slice.events.disableType("click");
    }
  });
});


pieSeries.appear(1000, 100);
chart.appear(1000, 100);
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
}
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/percent.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>



Hope that helps...

disabling for all slices does not seem to work for some reason

You should provide more information for your specific case. Otherwise you got two possible workarounds. In case the detailed example works for you you can modify the example check to:
if (dataItem.get("category"))
Other workaround should be disabling pointer events for the relevant chart element via pure CSS:
.am5-layer-0 { pointer-events: none; }

Your detailed example works, however, since i'm trying to disable for all slices, your first and simplest solution does not work for some reason. codepen.io/jonaspohren/pen/NWQLwbB

You're right, @JonasP. adjusted a little bit and you can now find a revised version of my initial answer. When you combine all three methods you will be able to remove both hover and click. Hope that helps.
